# docker container showing wrong time

Tags: docker

When I run date in my host,

```
~$ date
Fri May 19 07:06:50 UTC 2017
```

Similarly, I ran date in docker container,

```
$ docker exec -it bf0507306acc date
Thu May 18 22:49:43 UTC 2017
```

I have tested this in multiple containers like

```
mysql, fabric8/java-jboss-openjdk8-jdk:1.2.6.
```

The results are same. Docker container is showing wrong time (7.5 hrs delay). How can I fix this? Where docker picks this time?

Comment: Are you running ubunutu 16.04? There is a known bug

Comment: The JDK image, I use is using CentOS7. MySQL image is using debian. Surprisingly both has similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running mysql,then it's running on the top of Ubuntu OS(if you carefully check the image of Ubuntu). Now, you could use Ubuntu command `time` to change the time of the container. Otherwise, you can use NTP to synchronize the time from a server.